# Docker Phinx Migration getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php, docker

I am new to docker and am trying to containerize an existing PHP codebase that uses Phinx for migration purposes. When I go to run `docker-compose build` it starts to build the php service and throws the following error:

```
PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does
   not resolve
```

I'm assuming it has to do with the order of services or the mysql service in particular not running/setting the hostname for other services during the actual build process since hostname resolution works properly if the hostname lookup is done after the image is built and running.

Here is my docker-compose.yml contents:

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  nginx:
    build: './docker/nginx/'
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    links:
      - mysql
      - mysql:app

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - "mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=app
      - MYSQL_USER=app
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    restart: unless-stopped

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    restart: unless-stopped

  php:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: './docker/php/Dockerfile'
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
    links:
      - mysql
      - mysql:app

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

Here is my PHP Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2.7-fpm-alpine3.7
RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
    php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html
#RUN composer install --no-dev --no-interaction -o

RUN vendor/bin/phinx migrate
```

Comment: You can't run database migrations in a Dockerfile.  It doesn't have access to any other services, and it's not guaranteed to be re-run if the database container gets deleted and recreated.

Comment: What would be the proper method for doing this then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to put the php artisan migrate command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850813/where-to-put-the-php-artisan-migrate-command)